# Partial query failure for kql query size

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm getting this goofy error which looks to be related to query size. My working query takes around 3 mins. If I add another few lines (which should take ~3 secs if I have results from previous query), kusto throws partial query error due to query size.

I didn't realize that there was such a limit in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/concepts/resulttruncation. I've removed comments/tweaked some queries to spit out lesser fields but still running into same error.

Any idea about what's going on here?

Here's the error trace

[image: Error Trace]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error may be coming in a scenario of cross-cluster query. In this scenario Kusto (Azure Data Explorer) will generate a query and send to another cluster. The query can become long if it contains in() operator (and arguments of in() are coming from the query partial evaluation).
If you provide more details - of what is your scenario / query you're running - you can get more detailed answer.

Comment: This is exactly right. My query spans three Kusto clusters and in() is used liberally. Lemme rework the query. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I just ran into the same issue.  I'm not sure what your solution was for solving the in() operator.  But a colleague told me to use `.set` to create a temp table for the query.  He also mentioned `materialize`, but that did not work for me.